# How to add function to custom fields when page/post has a password?

Tags: functions, custom-field, password

I am wondering if there was a way to add a function in the function.php file where if the Page/Post has a password set, it automatically fills in a custom field?

I have to manually insert an html image code to show on the blog post grid an icon with a padlock, this is done by using a custom field. But having to update 1000's of pages/posts, I thought there might be an easier way to get the functions to add this code into the customs field when it detects the page/post has a password.

Comment: Is the html image code different for each post or the same for all?

Comment: Hello, it is same for all. Basically just wanted to add the same padlock icon for all password protected pages.